# MySQL said: Documentation #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

**Mysql function getLastMediaId()**

```
`BEGIN  
DECLARE Lid INT;  
select id into Lid FROM projectmedia order by id desc limit 1;  
RETURN(Lid);  
END`
```

**Mysql procedure**

```
`BEGIN   DECLARE lid INT;   
IF last_id=0 THEN SET lid=getLastMediaId();   
ELSE SET lid=last_id;   
END IF;   
SELECT * FROM projectmedia WHERE id < last_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;   
END`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced  **WHERE id < last_id** with  **WHERE id < lid**

```
SELECT * FROM projectmedia WHERE id < lid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
```